# Javascript file object equivalent in java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have some javascript code that looks like this

```
attachmentFiles.push(fileObj);
```

where `fileObj` is the file user has selected to upload.

Now if I want to represent in the java/json format, what should be the type of the list?

i.e

```
public class AttachmentHodler{
    List<?> attachmentFiles;


    public List<?> getAttachmentFiles() {
        return attachmentFiles;
    }

    public void setAttachmentFiles(List<?> attachmentFiles) {
        this.attachmentFiles = attachmentFiles;
    }

}
```

Comment: you misspelled `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to store in your `List`. You can even choose to use `List<?>`, which will allow you to store almost anything in it. But if your attachment objects are of type `Attachment`, I'do go with `List<Attachment>`. That would allow you to store only `Attachment` objects in the list.

Since in Javascript there are no classes, it might be worth to mention that in Java, every object is an instance of a "class". Sometimes you define classes yourself, sometimes you re-use classes inside a framework or library.

So there is no general answer to the question, what type your elements will have.

Comment: Sorry ..its the file Object in the javascript which gets pushed to this object ..surely ..it cant have some random type?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose of `fileObj`. Depending on what you want to do with it and what it's responsibilities are you could use:

- some specialized `Attachement` class that you would create. Most versatile approach from the OO perspective. Example: http://ideone.com/H23Za7
- An actual [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) that supports operation like `.delete()`.
- just a `String` to represent the path without any useful functionality.